# Conditional filtering with user declared variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, where-clause

I need to filter a table with a user declared variable value (that can assume 0, 1 or 2). If @variable = 2, then the table remains the same. If @variable = 0 or 1, then I need the query to filter only those values in the table. I'm thinking about something like that, but obviously it is not working:

```
@variable = (user input)

IF @variable = 2 THEN SELECT * FROM my_table
ELSE (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column = "@variable")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead use this

```
SET @variable := 1;
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE IF(@variable = 2,1=1,sID = @variable);
```

1=1 would give back all rows, the rest shows data from column = 2

Comment: I understood your code... the thing is that if @variable = 2 then it should return all rows. Else, it should return only the values on my_column that are equal to 1 or 0 (depending on @variable value). I think the way that I wrote my example was confusing, so I edited it. Should something like that work?

`SET @variable = 1;
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE IF(@variable = 2, 1=1, my_column = "@variable")`

Comment: yes this work too, i changeed the answer now when you have 2 you can get all rows. ande you can cascase the if clause it you have more, criteria